# Trying to get a indicator to read rays manually plotted in the chart

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

Tradingview appears to not support this, how can i get an indicator to read rays already plotted in the chart manually by hand?
I want to make an indicator plot these rays

Not able to get chart data

What would be another method to get a indicator or something to plot lines on the chart externally, so i give it the lines to plot and it will display it on the tradingview chart

Answer (score 0):

With pinescript v5 (and under), you can't get value from the chart.
You cannot either receive data from an external server.